# How to call C functions from nloptr package directly in an Rcpp package?

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp, nlopt

I am creating an R package that also has c++ codes using RcppArmadillo. One of the function needs to optimize a function. Currently, I imported the `nloptr::nloptr` function into c++ and then use it to optimize the function. The code is here: https://github.com/daijiang/phyr/blob/master/src/pglmm_gaussian.cpp#L267-L282; also line 244-245.

Because the backbone of `nloptr::nloptr` is written in C, calling the R function in c++ seems not the best way and probably will slow things down. Ideally, we should call its C functions directly in the c++ file. But I do not know how to do this given my very limited experience with c/c++. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: This is a cross-post over from https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr/issues/39 There is already a working sample package posted here: https://github.com/shrektan/rcpp_nlopt_example Please note that unlike the performance hit that occurs when calling _R_ code from _C++_, this isn't nearly the case when calling _C_ code from _C++_.

Comment: Thanks @coatless. Can you elaborate on "this isn't nearly the case when calling C code from C++"? I am not sure that I get it.

Comment: both can be grouped as a "low-level" language. Meaning that they fall very close to assemble or machine level. There is _less_ overhead associated with each language. _C++_ can sometimes be referred to as a high-level language because it provides more features (e.g. objects, exceptions, and operator overloads). However, it's not nearly as high level as _R_.

Comment: Thanks @coatless. The current optimization way in my code can take lots of time; but similar process in the `lme4` package is much much faster... This is the main reason I want to call the optim directly in c++, instead of c++ --> R function import to c++ --> c++ of remaining steps. Lots of hard steps to learn as mentioned by Dirk below. Thanks!

Comment: Your Github links are non-permanent and seems to point to a wrong location now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a somewhat active discussion of that [over at the nloptr repo](https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr/issues/39).

Your deeper problem is that nlopt needs linking, which gets you into operating system dependence which is harder to set up than a pure header-only library such as RcppArmadillo..  You will need to learn about that harder step, and there is no simple rule.  The RcppGSL package (and vignette, and Rcpp Book chapter) are a roughly equivalent example.

*Edit several months later:*  With the new [nloptr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nloptr) version out on CRAN, we wrote a demo package [RcppNLoptExamples](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppNLoptExample) (also on CRAN now) that shows how to use nlopt from C/C++ code via Rcpp to be called from R.

Comment: Thanks Dirk for your information. I will take a look at the RcppGSL package.